# How to always display extra large icons in windows 7 explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, icons

I view alot of pictures for QA duties. Is there anyway to always make Windows 7 display extra large icons when browsing through folders in windows explorer? Right now every time I change folders I need to zoom in to extra large icons every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the view to `Extra large icons` in a folder you're viewing. Press `alt` and open `Tools -> Folder Options`. In the `View` tab, press `Apply to Folders`. You should now be seeing huge icons everywhere.